# Switching from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I want to switch my HP desktop from Windows to Ubuntu. I followed many videos and tutorials to do the same. Many videos directed me to switch it using bootable drive Rufus. I used it and followed all the steps, however after i try to restart my PC is not starting up if I change the BOOT settings before starting the system. Can someone please help?

Comment: Did you prepare a bootable USB using Rufus in UEFI? What version of Ubuntu ISO image you downloaded? Did you make a clean install? After installation, did you reach Ubuntu logon screen? Please tell exactly where you were stuck. Please reply. Thanks.

Comment: yes I did prepare a bootable USB using Rufus. I downloaded 16.04 LTS. I was not able to get to the screen where I could see the OS. My screen is just stuck with HP brand name on it.

Comment: Did you make a full installation using USB bootable stick? After installation, did you reach GRUB menu? From GRUB menu, you will boot to Ubuntu. Were you stuck while booting after GRUB menu?

Comment: With Rufus you need to select the correct option according to the type of computer you have. For old PCs the Rufus defaults are fine (BIOS/ Legacy) but for new ones you need to change the settings to GPT/UEFI before burning the ISO. Then you need to assure it is booting in the proper mode (UEFI settings) and in some cases you need an additional boot parameter. Please [edit] and post your hardware specifications.

Comment: Yes I am stuck at GRUB Menu

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a seperate partition for EFI and boot at the beginning of your disk. Let's say Assign 210Mb to efi partition and 500MB to boot partition.
On the installation windows installation type > chose something else. if there is no other OS installed select all the partitions and click on `-` sign and delete all your partitions one by one. and then press `+` type of the new partion `primary`, Location for the new partition: `begining of this space` > use as: `EFI System partition` assign 210Mb.
2:- click again on free space Type of the new Partition `Primary`Location, `Beginning of this space` > Mount Point: `/boot` assign 500MB and okay.
3:- click again on free space and Location for the new partition `Primary`, Location `Beginning of this space`, Use as: EXT4, Mount Point: `/`. Finally Chose location for Device for boot loader installation: in my case it's `/dev/sda2/` the same partition we have created for `/boot`. chose and install now.